# How to make many variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

everyone!
I am pretty new at Javascript and I wanted to challenge myself by making a program that will figure out if the number entered is prime. So far, this is my code:

```
var a = prompt('What should the number be?');
var n = parseInt(a);           
var counter = n - 1;
var b = n/counter;
var c = Math.floor(b);
if (n < 1) {
            window.alert('Invalid: negative numbers are neither prime nor composite!');
        }
        if (n === 1){
            window.alert('1 is neither prime nor composite!');
        } else {
            if (b-c != 0) {

            }
        }
```

I am planning to make a bunch of variables, each with a name that differs by a number. I do not need an easier or different way to write my code. So how do I make the script write many different variable automatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for using an array.  It's an easy way to store lots of values in the same variable name, but called by an index - a number.  Check out the MDN page for [arrays](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array&ei=DRbDUeaSO_is4AOzm4GgBg&usg=AFQjCNHktfa1HeQ0BsF7hFbCDHykGL_TZQ&bvm=bv.48175248,d.dmg&cad=rja).

Here's an example of stashing lots of values in an array:

```
var bigNumber = 100000;
var myArray = new Array();
var tally = 0;
for( i = 0; i < bigNumber; i++ )
{
    tally += i;
    myArray[i] = tally;
}
```

When this is done, myArray will have 100000 values in it.  `myArray[0] = 0`,  `myArray[1] = 1`, `myArray[2] = 3`, `myArray[3] = 6`, `myArray[4] = 10`, etc.

Comment: I'm old school - I always forget about that.  I wanted to ensure that there were predictable numerical indexes on the values, since the original question included that idea.

Comment: how do i turn the array into a variable though

Comment: An array is a collection of variables.  Re-read the end of my answer, it shows how to access the individual values stored in the array.

Comment: how do i make the program automatically access the values of the array

Comment: Read up on loops - I used one to set the values in my example.  You can also use one to use all the values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your problems is with too many variables. You should use functions to separate code parts with different purpose:

```
function isPrime(n) {
    var counter = n - 1;
    var b = n / counter;
    var c = Math.floor(b);
    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n === 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (b - c != 0) {

        }
    }
}


var n = parseInt(prompt('What should the number be?'));
alert('The given number ' + n + ' is ' + (isPrime(n) ? '' : ' not') + ' a prime.');
```

or

```
function PrimeChecker(){
    var n = this.readNumber();
    this.displayResult(n, this.isPrime(n));
}
PrimeChecker.prototype = {
    readNumber: function (){
        return parseInt(prompt('What should the number be?'));
    },
    isPrime: function (n) {
        var counter = n - 1;
        var b = n / counter;
        var c = Math.floor(b);
        if (n < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n === 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (b - c != 0) {

            }
        }
    },
    displayResult: function (n, isPrime){
        alert('The given number ' + n + ' is ' + (isPrime ? '' : ' not') + ' a prime.');
    }
};

new PrimeChecker();
```

If you want to group variables you can still use an object to store them:

```
var map = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
map.d = 4;
map.e = 5;
alert(map.e);
```

If you generate variables without name, you can use an array:

```
var array= [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
];
array.push("d");
array.push("e");
alert(array[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The evil way to do it would be to create variables on the global object (window), like so:

```
// This is bad because it pollutes the global namespace:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  window['num' + i] = i;
}
```

A better way would be to create an empty object and use that as a namespace for your variables.

```
var o = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  o['num' + i] = i;
}
```